Question regarding conjunction and necessity in modal logic
I've been learning SQML, and I have a question regarding conjunction and necessity.
How do you prove the following theorem, or is it not generally true?
⊢ □(A ∧ B) → □A ∧ □B

what have you tried?

@emesupap, I haven't tried anything, it just seems intuitively true.

It is true, and also the other direction. See Modal Logic. Intuitively, the Necessity operator acts as the universal quantifier.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, how do you prove it?

From the necessity of the conjunction you derive the conjunction, then unpack it using Conjunction Elimination and apply Nec rule to both. Then repack using Conjunction Intro.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I don't think that will work, since NEC is a rule of proof, not a rule of inference.  Show me what you mean in an answer.  I fear you need Kripke semantics.

@leepappas sqml is sound and complete. So you can work both ways

By necessitation, □(A ∧ B → A), by distribution, □(A ∧ B) → □A. Repeat for B and introduce ∧ between □A and □B.

I’m voting to close this question because not a forum for homework questions

Answers to questions are better posted in the answer box rather than as edits to the questions. You are allowed to post answers to your own questions and even to accept them.

This has been answered in the comments.  Here is the solution.

All tautologies are theorems.
A ∧ B → A is a tautology.
⊢ A ∧ B → A
⊢ □[A ∧ B →A] [3,NEC]
⊢ □[A ∧ B →A] → (□[A ∧ B] →□A) [distribution]
⊢ □[A ∧ B] →□A [4,5; MP]
⊢ □[A ∧ B] →□B [similar to 2-6]
⊢ □[A ∧ B] →□A ∧ □B [6,7; Identical assumptions]

